# How to upgrade the jar file from jdk 1.4 to jdk 1.6?

Tags: grails, jar, search-engine, java

I have a jar file named jse.jar built into jdk 1.4 which i downloaded from http://www.me.lv/jse/manualservlet.html for search engine application. Now the issue is that I want to use it in my jdk 1.6 application. When I use it, it throws an error describing the older version of jdk is a root cause of this error.

Now I want to upgrade all the classes of jar file and jar file itself to jdk 1.6. Can anybody help me out to meet my requirements. and if possible then can anybody help me with the newer version of this java search engine jse.jar.

Ideas to implement Website full text search in java and grails(without domain classes) will be acceptable as well.

Thanks a ton in advance..

Comment: Try to find using google the version for jdk 1.6. Probably that jar file contains deprecated methods. Try to find the same file, or some that give you the same functionality.

Comment: you can use lucient search engine for seaching functionality. see on http://lucene.apache.org/core/

Comment: @Deckard27 Thanks for the answer but i already have tried for newer jar on google. I couldn't find it. And  yes, the classes in the jar above contains some deprecated methods. Can you help me how can i implement full text search engine in my application? Actually i want to implement it in grails application. but all the grails plugins requires domain classes and my application doesn't have any domain class. So i will adopt java solution for my grails app. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hardik Patel have said a good thing, use for that Lucene.

Comment: @HardikPatel Thanks but for grails, it requires domain classes and which I'm running short of... Any Solution for Java? Which i can use directly by adding jars.

Comment: try to find that jar using jarfinder page, i think that there you can find a new version of that jar.

Comment: " When I use it, it throws an error describing the older version of jdk is a root cause of this error."  -- Just curious, what exactly is the error message.

Comment: @JigarPatel Have you found any solution with jse.jar?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many open source search engine support in java. Like Egothor,Nutch,Lucene etc.. Look at this http://java-source.net/open-source/search-engines. I think it may be help you